# OSM data appear in very low quality in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-openlayers-plugin

This is my first map creation attempt in QGIS 2.8.2. I am having trouble in making it look good though with OpenStreetMap (OSM) street map data in particular. 
I import data via `Web>OpenLayers Plugin>OpenStreetMap`.

I don't understand why the quality is so low, when it should be looking like that:

http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=13/52.9474/-1.1467

[image]

Might be something I have missed but I can't seem to find anything similar online. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Openstreetmap background looks best if you hit exactly the scales in which the tiles are rendered.

You might look into the [TileMapScaleLevels](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/TileMapScaleLevels/) plugin to get those scales by default.